# YouTube API quota been reduced

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have encounter some problems when using YouTube API recently, and I would like to ask if you have the same problem like I do and if anyone have any solution.

Before, I had 100 millions and 50 millions quotas per day, but I just found out that the quota of some keys with less usage has decreased a lot (500 millions has decreased to 300K and the one with 1 million has decreased to 600K and 10K  )

The info that I found are all from the project of 2016, and the quotas are all 10K or other case like the whole project had been shut down, so the quota is 0. And none of them is the same as the problem that we have encountered. So I would like to ask if anybody knows why does this happen and how can we prevent and resolve it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The default quota limit is now 10,000 units:

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of 10 thousand units per day, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users...
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Previously they had given 1 million units to new accounts. My own APIs were each reduced from 1 million to 10k also, because I never use even 5k units. You can ask for more units if you reach the quota limit, inside your Developer Console, `IAM & Admin` > `Quotas` > `EDIT QUOTAS`:

[image]

Comment: it is about 85 search requests (like literally keyword searches) equivelant with no way of getting statistics info of the only maximum of 50 videos you can find. I think this is the youtube's way of saying "can you just scrape our website with selenium".

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase your Quota is to fill out this form https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form and submit your request to YouTube. Then you have to wait no less than two weeks.
Be careful: if your app doesn't respect YouTube TOS, they will terminate it