# Search for single youtube video with keywords

Tags: web-applications, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating a web app that requests a search to the youtube data api using keyword to then return the video id of the most popular video, i have successfully done this by sending a get request to 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search' although i then soon realised that each search request uses up 100 quotas when i have a limit of 10,000 so my question is, is is there an alternative method to get the same result im looking for? and if not how can i increase my quotas limit and how much will it cost?

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
        part: 'snippet',
        q: (title + " by " + artist),
        type: 'video',
        maxResults: 1,
        key: '******************'
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data.items[0].id.videoId)
    })
```

Comment: you should add a condition to limit the data with a most appropriate result. Just saying, i don't think changing the method will decrease the data. You should be more strict on getting the desired result.

Comment: @parladneupane thank you and by doing this will it decrease the quotas cost? And if so what conditions should I add as I'm new to this?

Comment: Hello don't share your private API key on the web. :) How are you identifying the most popular video? Through view count, or likes? 
You can ask for more quota this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394232/youtube-api-quota-been-reduced/56404826#56404826

Comment: @Bman70 I am selecting the video through relevence, and is requesting more quotas free?

Comment: @JoshuaAttridge the `search` request has a [cost of 100 points](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), so, if you're planning using the `search`, you'll need more quota, and for that, you have to contact YouTube for ask them more quota *(though, that is a paid service - which I cnouldn't find clear information about it)*. I'm just guessing here, but, if the quota is a problem, try using other tool, like Google search API or other tool that lets you search for videos on YouTube...

Comment: That's great thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `search` request has a [cost of 100 points](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), so, if you're planning using the search, you'll need more quota, and for that, you have to contact YouTube for ask them more quota (`though, that is a paid service - which I couldn't find clear information about it`).

I'm just guessing here, but, if the quota is a problem, try using other tool, like [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) or other tool that lets you search for videos on YouTube.