# How to query for total views of every video on a YouTube channel using YouTube Data API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a small project that must query for every video on a YouTube channel and return the video title and total views for that video. I've figure out a way to handle this, but the quota cost is rather steep for a channel of over 1500 videos (about 300 quota points), so I was curious if there was a more efficient way to query for such information.

The steps I currently have to take are threefold:

1. Query the current user and find their uploads playlist id using `channels`
2. Use the playlist id to query for videos in that playlist using `playlistItems` (this step returns video information like title and videoId)
3. Parse out the video ids from step 2 and query for a list of videos that returns the statistics for each video using `videos`

I then merge the results from 2 and 3 to create an object that contains both video information and statistics.

```
  {
    videoId: 'abc1-345dgh'
    title: 'Video Title',
    thumbnail: {
      img: 'image information'
    },
    views: 12345567
  }
```

Is there a better way to return a list of videos with video information and view statistics?

**Here are the steps I have to take:**

```
const channel = await youtubeAPI.channels.list({
    part: 'contentDetails',
    mine: true
  });

const playlistId = channel.data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

const videos = await getPlaylistVideos(playlistId);
```

The `playlistId` of the users uploads playlist is sent to `getPlaylistVideos()` which iterates over each page of results from a `playlistItems` query.

```
var videos = [];
var videoStats = [];

async function getPlaylistVideos(playlistId, pageToken = null) {

  const res = await youtubeAPI.playlistItems.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    playlistId: playlistId,
    maxResults: 50,
    pageToken: pageToken
  });

  const mappedVideos = res.data.items.map((item) => {
    return {
      title: item.snippet.title,
      thumbnail: item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres,
      videoId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId
    }
  })

  videos.push(...mappedVideos);
  // if there's another page to get results from
  if ('nextPageToken' in res.data) {
    return await getPlaylistVideos(playlistId, res.data.nextPageToken)
  } else {
    // we've queried for everything, return the videos
    return videos;
  }
}
```

Next, I filter out the video Ids returned from the `videos` array

```
const videoIds = videos.map((video) => {
    return video.videoId
  });

videoIdArray.push(...videoIds);

const videoStats = await getVideoStats(videoIdArray);
```

These ids get sent to `getVideoStats()` and I iterate through all video ids and return statistics for each video

```
var minId = 0;
var maxId = 50;

async function getVideoStats(videoIds) {

  // since we can only return 50 videos per query, I have to slice the
  // videoId array into segments
  const videoIdLength = videoIds.length;
  const subsetIds = videoIds.slice(minId, maxId);

  const res = await youtubeAPI.videos.list({
    part: 'statistics',
    id: subsetIds.join(","),
    maxResults: 50
  });

  const mappedVideoStats = res.data.items.map((item) => {
    return {
      videoId: item.id,
      views: item.statistics.viewCount
    }
  });

  videoStats.push(...mappedVideoStats);

  const diff = videoIdLength - (maxId + 1);

  if (diff > 0) {
    // if there are more videos to query, update the variables used 
    // in slice() to take 50 more videos
    minId += 50;
    maxId += 50;
    return await getVideoStats(videoIds);
  } else {
    return videoStats;
  }

}
```

Lastly, I merge the video information with the video statistics by looking for matching `videoId` properties in each object:

```
let mergedArray = [];

  videos.forEach((video, index) => {
    mergedArray.push(Object.assign({}, video, videoStats[index]))
  })
```

`mergedArray` finally stores the information that I need.

This is the info I need, I just feel like I had to jump through hoops to get to it. Is there a more efficient method for achieving the same task? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You can save *some* quota by changing the code you're using for retrieve the "uploads" playlist from a given channel. [Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/4092887) about the change you have to make in the `channel_id` in order to get the `uploads` playlist.
- My second option would be using Google Custom Search API (*[as I describe in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821075/4092887)*) - since in YouTube Data API dwill always consume the same quota - no matter how many parameters/terms you use in each request.

These are just my two cents, but, might be worth try it.